# How access objects (tables) of Other Users in Oracle DB using Python tools (SQLAlchemy, cx_Oracle, etc.)?

Tags: python, sql, oracle, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have read access to other users' tables. How can I read them into pandas dataframe or just download as `*.csv` using Python tools?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to install cx_oracle and SQLAlchemy.

```
import cx_Oracle
import sqlalchemy as sa
import pandas as pd

engine = sa.create_engine ('oracle+cx_oracle://user:pwd@host:port/dbname')
connection = engine.connect()
df = pd.read_sql("select * from otheruser.table", connection)
df.head()
df.to_csv("file.csv")
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It was very helpful. After several tries I had to use `cx_oracle` without `sqlalchemy`.

Answer (score 0):

In `sqlalchemy` table schemas are managed by the `MetaData` object. To load schemas from an existing database, you can use the `MetaData.reflect()` method which can take an optional parameter `schema` that is used to load schemas from other users.
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.reflect

To load it as a pandas `DataFrame`, you can either use the `read_sql_query()` method.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql_query.html

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://user:pwd@host:port/dbname")
meta = sa.Metadata()
meta.reflect(bind=engine, schema="otheruser")
table = sa.Table("otheruser.table", meta, autoload_with=engine)
df = pd.read_sql_query(table.select(), engine)
df.to_csv("file.csv")
```